# Firebird 2.1 stored procedure to concatenate text on multiple rows

Tags: stored-procedures, concatenation, firebird, firebird2.1

I am trying to write a stored procedure to concatenate multiple rows of text together to return it as a single string. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
 ID INTEGER,
 SEQ INTEGER,
 TEXT VARCHAR(255));

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO TEST (ID, SEQ, TEXT) VALUES (1, 1, "LINE 1");
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, SEQ, TEXT) VALUES (1, 2, "LINE 2");
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, SEQ, TEXT) VALUES (1, 3, "LINE 3");

COMMIT;

SET TERM !!;
CREATE PROCEDURE concat_names (iID INTEGER)
  RETURNS (CONCAT VARCHAR(2000))
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE name VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  CONCAT = '';
  FOR SELECT TEXT FROM TEST where id=:iID INTO :name
  DO BEGIN
    CONCAT = CONCAT || name;
  END
END!!
SET TERM ;!!

commit;
```

However when I run:

```
select concat from concat_names(1);
```

It always returns zero rows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forget for SUSPEND. Your proc should look like this:

```
SET TERM !!;
CREATE PROCEDURE concat_names (iID INTEGER)
  RETURNS (CONCAT VARCHAR(2000))
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE name VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  CONCAT = '';
  FOR SELECT TEXT FROM TEST where id=:iID INTO :name
  DO BEGIN
    CONCAT = CONCAT || name;
  END
  SUSPEND;
END!!
SET TERM ;!!
```

You can achieve the same result without stored proc. Use LIST aggregate function:

```
SELECT LIST(text, '') FROM TEST where id=:iID
```

Second parameter of LIST is a delimiter. If you call LIST with only field name, then comma ',' will be used to separate values.

Comment: Hi Andrei, the SUSPEND bit works but the LIST doesn't because you cannot guarantee the order the rows will be returned by the Select statement. If you order by the SEQ column you then need to group by it, which would then not return the correct results. I had already tried this thinking that it would be more efficient. By the way, are you Andrei K from GBS?

Comment: Opps, sorry, wrong letter order GSB. Golden Software, Belarus

Answer (score 0):

In the case the field TEST can ben null and you don't want to set to null the whole result it is useful to use:

```
 CONCAT = CONCAT || coalesce(name,'');
```

instead of

```
CONCAT = CONCAT || name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without utilizing a Stored Proc and using version Firebird 2.5, the **LIST** aggregation function will return "Comma-separated string concatenation of non-NULL values in the column"*. Using the aforementioned TEST table, the SQL

```
SELECT LIST(TEXT)
    FROM TEST
```

returns

LINE 1,LINE 2,LINE 3

This may be of some interest.

*Taken from the Firebird reference page [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/nullguide-aggrfunc.html)